# Performance of wsgi file important?

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've built a website using the (awesome) Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/), which I'm now deploying on AWS. For this I create a wsgi file which looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/myawesomewebsite')
from app import app as application
```

Since I always try to avoid hardcoding strings into code I changed this to the following:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
from app import app as application
```

What I now wonder about is whether the performance of the wsgi file matters (with respect to the additional overhead of `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`).

Is the wsgi file parsed and executed with every web-request, or is it loaded only once when apache is started? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wsgi file is executed when your application server loads your app.

Using Apache, this will likely happen once in a while when Apache recycles a worker thread / process. The same goes for other application servers (e.g. Gunicorn will run the WSGI file once per worker).

You're fine.

Comment: Apache only recycles whole processes, never a single thread within  process. The comment about Apache recycling processes also is only valid if using mod_wsgi embedded mode, not daemon mode. One should always use daemon mode if one can. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html